# Designing a DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata, dfa, automata-theory

I want to design a DFA for the following language after fixing ambiguity.
I thought and tried a lot but couldn't get a proper answer.

```
S->aA|aB|lambda
A->aA|aS
B->bB|aB|b
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend first getting an NFA by considering this to be a regular grammar; then, determinize the NFA, and then we can write down a new grammar that's equivalent to this one but unambiguous (for the same reason the determinized automaton is deterministic). Writing down the NFA for this grammar is easy: productions of the form `X -> sY` translate into transitions from state `X` to state `Y` on input `s`. Similarly, transitions of the form `X -> lambda` mean `X` is an accepting state, and transitions of the form `X -> b` imply a new accepting state that transitions to a dead state.

We need states for each nonterminal symbol `S`, `A` and `B`; and we will have transitions for every production. Our NFA looks like this:

```
       /---a----\
       |        |
       V        |
----->(S)--a-->(A)<--\
       |        |    |
       a        \--a-/   /--a,b--\
       |                 |       |
       V                 V       |
 /--->(B)--b-->(X)-a,b->(Y)<-----/
 |     |
 \-a,b-/
```

Here, states `(S)` and `(X)` are accepting, state `(Y)` is a dead state (we didn't really need to depict this explicitly, but bear with me) and this automaton is totally equivalent to the grammar. Now, we need to determinize this. States of the determinized automaton will correspond to subsets of states from the nondeterministic version. Our first deterministic state will correspond to the set containing just `(S)`, and we will figure out the other required subsets (of which we can have at most 32, since we have 5 states and 2 to the power of 5 is 32) using the transitions:

```
Q               s    Q'
{(S)}           a    {(A),(B)}
{(S)}           b    empty
{(A),(B)}       a    {(A),(B),(S)}
{(A),(B)}       b    {(B),(X)}
{(A),(B),(S)}   a    {(A),(B),(S)}
{(A),(B),(S)}   b    {(B),(X)}
{(B),(X)}       a    {(B),(Y)}
{(B),(X)}       b    {(B),(X),(Y)}
{(B),(Y)}       a    {(B),(Y)}
{(B),(Y)}       b    {(B),(X),(Y)}
{(B),(X),(Y)}   a    {(B),(Y)}
{(B),(X),(Y)}   b    {(B),(X),(Y)}
```

We encountered six states, plus a dead state (`empty`) which we can name `q1` through `q6`, plus `qD`. All of the states corresponding to subsets with either `(S)` or `(X)` in them are accepting, and `(S)` is the initial state. Our DFA looks like this:

```
                  /-a,b-\
                  |     |
                  V     |
----->(q1)--b-->(qD)----/
       |
       a          /--a--\
       |          |     |
       V          V     |
      (q2)--a-->(q3)----/
       |         |
       b         |
       |         b
       V         |
  /--(q4)<------/     /--b--\
  |   |               |     |
  |   \------b------(q6)<---+
  a     /--a----\    |      |
  |     |       |    |      |
  \-->(q5)<-----+--a-/      |
        |                   |
        \---------b---------/
```

Finally, we can read off the unambiguous regular grammar from our DFA:

```
(q1) -> a(q2) | b(qD) | lambda
(qD) -> a(qD) | b(qD)
(q2) -> a(q3) | b(q4)
(q3) -> a(q3) | b(q4) | lambda
(q4) -> a(q5) | b(q6) | lambda
(q5) -> a(q5) | b(q6)
(q6) -> a(q5) | b(q6) | lambda
```

Comment: thank you sir but I made a mistake.B rules are like this:

```B->bA|bB|b
```
can you change the machine to fit this rule?

Comment: @Davood In what sense is the machine mistaken?

Comment: I made a mistake in rules.I mentioned in the first comment